# Specific volume formula for a fixed vessel not making sense

Tags: thermodynamics, volume

The specific volume $v_{avg}$ for the liquid-vapour mixture phase is given as $v_{avg}=m_fv_f+m_gv_g$

In the textbook, diagrammatically, this is shown as: [image]

So, as the mixture is heated or cooled, $v_{avg}$ can vary along the horizontal line.

However, $v_{avg}$ is also given as being equal to $V/m$ where $V$ is the volume of the closed vessel it is in. This is implied by the textbook mentioning at the start of the derivation that the system is a tank.

[image]

However, since total mass is fixed, and the volume is as well, this would imply $v_{avg}$ is too.

If $V/m$ = $v_{avg}$ is fixed, then it's value would be the same regardless of if it's liquid, gas, or at any point in the mixture phase. So we wouldn't be able to identify the state of the system with this information. Yet the textbook has, in solved examples, used this to determine the state of a system.

My speculation is, that during the above step of the derivation, V, which equals the sum, doesn't actually represent the tank volume. However, they have used it being equal to the tank volume in many solved examples.

Comment: What is the problem with $V$ or  $v_{avg}$ constant?

Comment: @GiorgioP The problem is the textbook is implying that in this situation that $v_{avg}$ can vary. And secondly, they have used $V/m$ to identify the state of a system (rigid tank with water at some pressure) in solved examples. Whereas if it's value is constant then it would be so regardless of if it's in liquid, gas or some point in the mixture phase.

Comment: Shouldnt your first equation include the total mass:  $m_tv_{avg}=m_fv_f+m_gv_g$

Comment: @SteveSaban Correct, forgot show the whole thing divide by the total mass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mass m is constant and the tank volume V is constant, then $v_{avg}=\frac{V}{m}$ is constant for any changes that occur within the tank.  So any changes in temperature and/or pressure will be accompanied only by changes in the relative masses of liquid and vapor.

Comment: Well, the diagram I posted, the textbook has provided for the derivation where they have assumed a tank. And in it, $v_{avg}$ is varying. Also, if V/m is always constant, that would imply it's useless in identifying the state of this system. Because it would be the same regardless of if it is in liquid phase, gas phase or any point during the transition. Yet, the textbook has used it to identify the state in solved examples. An example would be the related question I had posted.

Comment: Who says vavg is varying along the horizontal line.  Once V and m are specified, vavg is fixed.

Comment: If it's fixed, then how can $V/m$ be used to identify the state of the system. Since this value would be the same regardless of if it's a liquid, gas, or any point in the mixture phase. Yet they have done this in solved examples

Comment: Is V/m the only parameter that determines the state of the system?

Comment: V/m and pressure. But I guess what I'm saying is V/m is not a parameter at all since it's the same regardless of state

Comment: That's like saying that temperature is not a state parameter at all because you are restricting you[rself to isothermal paths.

Answer (score 0):

Specific volume is really just the inverse density. Since mass is conserved and the total volume is fixed, the total density remains fixed even though it's a sum of two different densities whose ratio changes with temperature.
This is what allows for the calculation of quality. The equation below expresses it as a conservation of mass in a total fixed volume

$V_g\rho_g + V_f\rho_f = V_{total}\rho_{total} $

Comment: I guess what I'm having trouble with is: Suppose you have water in a tank 1/4th filled and you heat it. In the gaseous phase $V/m$ makes sense to me as the specific volume. However, in the liquid phase wouldn't it be $(V/4)/m$?

Comment: So when we're comparing this value to values on a table, the value on the table represents the $(V/4)/m$ so to say, while what we have computed is $V/m$